# Need help for the correct values in a HTTP post (I think)

Tags: php, http-post

So i've never worked with PHP or http posting or anything before, so please excuse me if i'm asking something dumb.

Heres a site so I can explain more accurately what I need.

http://nycserv.nyc.gov/NYCServWeb/NYCSERVMain

So I want to write something that will get the resultant page info as if I had hit the "go" button next to where it says "consumer fair violation". After doing a bunch of googling, I think i'm supposed to do HTTP posting, so i've been messing around with PHP and CURl. This is the code i've came up with, although I'm not sure what values i'm supposed to actually post.

```
<?php

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://nycserv.nyc.gov/NYCServWeb/NYCSERVMain");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);

$data = array(
    'dcadropdownmenu.name' => 'javascript:consumerAffairsViolationsQuerySetup("GET_CONSUMER_AFFAIRS_VIOLATION_SEARCH_QUERY_SETUP")');

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
$output = curl_exec($ch);
$info = curl_getinfo($ch);
curl_close($ch);

print $info;
print $output;
?>
```

I'm pretty sure i'm not supposed to be setting dvaddropdowmenu.name, but I dont know what I am supposed to be posting. Any help would be great.

**UPDATE**
So I finally got it to work. The problem i'm having now is how to HTTP post again on the returning page from the original. What I mean, is I got it to return the HTML from the page as if I hit the Go button. Now I need to hit the search button on this returned page. I tried just changing the post variables and exec'ing again, but that didn't work. Any help?

Comment: Look into the Tamper Data Firefox extension, that will let you see exactly what variables are being posted to which URL. You're on the right track, I saw lots of javascript: strings being POSTed.

Comment: So it's not something really simple, like just one variable?

Answer (score 0):

It took some digging through the JavaScript to find it, but here's the form that's actually being submitted:

```
form name=​"NycservProtocolForm" method=​"POST" action=​"NYCSERVMain">​
    <center>​…​</center>​
    <!--    N Y C S E R V   P R O T O C O L    -->
    <input type=​"HIDDEN" name=​"ChannelType" value=​"ct/​Browser">​
    <input type=​"HIDDEN" name=​"RequestType" value=​"rt/​Business">​
    <input type=​"HIDDEN" name=​"SubSystemType" value=​"st/​Payments">​
    <input type=​"HIDDEN" name=​"AgencyType" value=​"at/​PVO">​
    <input type=​"HIDDEN" name=​"ServiceName" value=​"NONE">​
    <input type=​"HIDDEN" name=​"MethodName" value=​"NONE">​
    <input type=​"HIDDEN" name=​"PageID" value=​"NYCSERVHome">​
    <input type=​"HIDDEN" name=​"ParamCount" value=​"0">​
    <input type=​"HIDDEN" name=​"NycservRequest" value=​"EMPTY">​
    <input type=​"HIDDEN" name=​"SearchType" value=​"EMPTY">​
    <input type=​"HIDDEN" name=​"LinkType" value=​"EMPTY">​
</form>
```

Depending on how familiar with the form you are, you can decide how many of these arguments you send. But these are the variables you want to specify when you send your POST request.

Comment: Do I have to enter the variables in a different way because the input type is hidden?

Comment: @Jack Not at all. PHP doesn't care what form type it was, just the name and the value.

Comment: Aftter trying, all my script returns is Error: 500. Any idea what that means?

Comment: Ahh! So I changed the code a bit and it works. The problem is, i'm not getting the correct data. This is coming up somewhere in the HTML, "Your session has timed out or expired.  Please follow the link to the home page."  How do I fix this?

Comment: @Jack When the page is first loaded, it tries to set a session cookie. What you'll have to do is just use [get_headers](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-headers.php) the first time, and look through the returned array for the session id. Then send your CURL post request, and include that session id.